# How to get data from a combobox using Beautifulsoup and Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Im trying to get the selected text from a combobox.
I was using asfad to search the text for the "selected" state but in the source code there are two items with that state, and I only want the one that is selected.

I am using the following code to search for it by the "span" and the id but I get the following:

```
login_request = session.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers, 
cookies=cookies)
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').find("span",id="sexo- 
button").get_text(strip=True)
print(sexo)
```

> Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

And it was also looking for it in the following way, obtaining a "none"

```
login_request = session.post(url,data=payload, headers=headers, 
cookies=cookies)
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').select('select[name=sexo] option[selected]') 
[0].value
print(sexo)
```

Origin:

```
<tr class="FacetFilaTD"><td class="FacetDataTDPADL5">Sexo</td><td colspan="3" 
class="FacetFieldCaptionTD">
<div class="control-valid"><select name="sexo" style="width: 140px; display: none;" id="sexo" 
class="clasecombo_valid" tabindex="0" aria-disabled="false">
<option selected="" value="">[SELECCIONAR]</option><option value="M" 
selected="">Masculino</option><option value="F">Femenino</option></select><span><a class="ui- 
selectmenu ui-widget ui-state-default ui-selectmenu-dropdown ui-state-active ui-corner-top" 
id="sexo-button" role="button" href="#nogo" tabindex="0" aria-haspopup="true" aria-owns="sexo- 
menu" aria-disabled="false" style="width: 140px;"><span class="ui-selectmenu- 
status">Masculino</span><span class="ui-selectmenu-icon ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s"></span> 
</a></span><span class="requerido">*</span></div>                                                                      
</td></tr>
```

I just want to get the selected item which in this case is "Masculino"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can see of the html, there is no `span` with `id="sexo-  button"`, so `BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').find("span",id="sexo-  button")` would have returned `None`, which is why you got the error from `get_text`.

As for your second attempt, I don't think bs4 Tags have a `value` property,  which is why you'd be getting `None` that time.

You should actually try combining the two like:

```py
sexo = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').select_one('select[name=sexo] option[selected]').get_text(strip=True)
```

(If it doesn't work, you should individually print to  see what `...select_one('select[name=sexo]')` and `...select_one('select[name=sexo] option[selected]')` will return, in case the page itself wasn't loaded properly by `session`)

You should also note that with the combined code, you'll actually get `[SELECCIONAR]`, since that's also selected according to the html provided. To skip that, you can instead try:

```py
selectedOpts = BeautifulSoup(login_request.text, 'lxml').select('select[name=sexo] option[selected]')
selectedOpts = [s for s in selectedOpts if s.get('value')]
sexo = selectedOpts[0] if selectedOpts else None
```

Comment: I used the code to skip the [SELECT], but when printing it throws me the whole line of code
>>>>: <option selected="" value="M">Masculino</option>
how can i get only the text "Masculino"?
Sorry bro, Im newbie

Comment: I only add ".get_text(strip=True)" in the last line of code, Thanks Bro!!!!!